# Force the parent to reap a child process <defunct>

Tags: c++, linux, zombie-process

I've been trying desperately to kill a child process from the parent.

I've tried:
1.    kill -15 pid

1. kill -shotgun pid
2. kill -9 pid

They all resolved in having the child process written as :
"defunct" (zombie) when ps -A in linux.

How do I kill the process and force it to be cleaned from the process table. I must have it cleaned because its lack of a record in the process table is how I verify in my code that the process is dead.

Thanks :-)

Comment: Is the parent process yours? You could orphan the child immediately with double-fork-and-exec...

Comment: Wait what, ``-shotgun``?

Comment: @ jonas yeah I saw it somewhere here...ik ik

Comment: I fork, the child process is replaced as it invokes execv. I want to kill the process THAT REPLACED THE CHILD.

Comment: @user1432779 That shotgun is, from what I know, a Meme from the Bastard Operator from Hell stories (google it).

Comment: A zombie process is already killed. So you can't kill it more. You can reap its return value with waitpid, as the OS is expecting you to do. After that, the zombie will disappear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to collect the child process, you have to ask for its exit code using `waitpid`. From the manpage:

> A child that terminates, but has not been waited for  becomes  a  "zombie".  The kernel maintains a minimal set of information about the zombie process (PID, termination status, resource  usage  information)  in order to allow the parent to later perform a wait to obtain information about the child.  As long as a zombie is not removed  from  the  system via  a wait, it will consume a slot in the kernel process table, and if this table fills, it will not be possible to create further  processes.

Usage is somewhat like:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

...
waitpid(child_pid, 0, 0);
```

If you want to return immediately, even if the child has not exited yet:

```
waitpid(child_pid, 0, WNOHANG);
```

If you just want to collect all zombie children, without finding information about a specific child, you do:

```
waitpid(-1, 0, WNOHANG);
```

You could do that in a loop until `waitpid` returns with a negative number (i.e. error) and errno indicates ECHILD.

This, by the way, also allows you to actually find out what state the process has, read up on the manpage for further information.

Comment: If I get it right, the parent ,by calling the waitpid, will block and wait until the child process has died?

Comment: Yes, unless you use `WNOHANG`.